# Python code is taking too long to decompress file and writing into google cloud storage as compared to local file system

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-storage, gzip, shutil

Its quite weird,
**All I am trying to do is decompress the file and save it**.
file is having

```
size: 16 Mb
extension = .json.gz
Source location = Google Cloud Storage
Destination location = Google Cloud Storage / Local File System
```

When I use

```
%%time
import gzip
import shutil
import gcsfs
with gcp_file_system.open('somebucket/<file.json.gz>','rb') as fl_:
    with gzip.open(fl_, 'rb') as f_in:        
        with gcp_file_system.open('somebucket/<file.json>','wb') as f_out:
            shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out)
```

It produces:  `Wall time: 5min 51s`

But when I try the same and change destination to Local machine

```
%%time
import gzip
import shutil
import gcsfs
with gcp_file_system.open('somebucket/<file.json.gz>','rb') as fl_:
    with gzip.open(fl_, 'rb') as f_in:        
        with open('localdir/<file.json>','wb') as f_out:
            shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out)
```

It produces:  `Wall time: 8.28 s`

Am not sure, what is playing role like buf_size, network speed, some gcsfs backend.

Comment: Rewrite your code into individual steps and then time each step. That will help indicate which step is the problem. My guess is your problem is using `gcsfs` instead of the SDK APIs. I would also check the Function log files for a possible cold start problem.

Comment: Do you use a VM? A Cloud Functions? Something else on Google Cloud? What's the configuration?

Comment: Its a local physical machine. 16Gigs RAM 8 vCPU, pretty nice one

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a gcsfs file, use the [`BlobReader`](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/storage/latest/google.cloud.storage.fileio.BlobReader) class from the GCS client library, for example:

Local Destination

```py
%%time
import gzip
import shutil
from google.cloud import storage
from google.cloud.storage import fileio 

storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.bucket('my_bucket')
blob = bucket.blob('file.json.gz')
reader = fileio.BlobReader(blob)
f_out = open('localdir/file.json','wb')
gz = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=reader, mode="rb")
shutil.copyfileobj(gz, f_out)
f_out.close()
gz.close()
reader.close()
```

GCS Destination:

```py
%%time
import gzip
import shutil
from google.cloud import storage
from google.cloud.storage import fileio 

storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.bucket('my_bucket')
blob_in = bucket.blob('file.json.gz')
reader = fileio.BlobReader(blob_in)
blob_out = bucket.blob('file.json')
writer = fileio.BlobWriter(blob_out)
gz = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=reader, mode="rb")
shutil.copyfileobj(gz, writer)
gz.close()
reader.close()
writer.close()
```

Comment: Thanks @David, does above code means, write locally and and then upload a copy of that. Cause if thats the case it might not suitable for large files.

Comment: Oops I only did the "local copy" version. I have now added a version for decrypting and then writing back to GCS. The "GCS Destination" version does not write to a local file and should scale to large files.